# Why does everybody hook add_rewrite_rule on init

Tags: rewrite-rules

Every example I find of adding rewrtie rules looks like

```
function addsomerule() {
  add_rewrite_rule(some regex,some parse result);
}

add_action('init','addsomerule');
```

This doesn't compute for me. as additions to rewrite rules of this kind are being ignored if the `rewrite_rule` option is not empty (i.e. there was no rewrite rules flush just now) so what is the point of hooking it there?

It seems like hooking it on `admin_init` makes much more sense as writes to DB, and therefor rewrite flush, should happen only on admin side.

Isn't there a more logical action to use this function or is it either init, or go with the lower level filter?

Comment: Because you want the rewrite on the front-end, not just the dashboard?...

Comment: @cale_b, I don't get what you mean. As I wrote, add_rewrite_rules almost 100% of the time when used at this way just does nothing at all, whether it is on the front end or dashboard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are right saying that without flushing rules, `add_rewrite_rule()` does not work, and the reason is that WordPress fetches rules from database, and `add_rewrite_rule()` does *not* add the rule to database.

However, is not possible to use `admin_init` and the reason is that `admin_init` is too late.

WordPress sometimes calls `flush_rewrite_rules()` on admin screens before that `admin_init` is fired (for example [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3caaa702bf3a307952a9562400104ba429b95c2b/wp-admin/admin.php#L36)), and to be sure the rule is added when WordPress calls `flush_rewrite_rules()` you need to use `init` (or maybe `wp_loaded`).

Something like this could work:

```
function addsomerule() {
  if ( is_admin() ) add_rewrite_rule(some regex,some parse result);
}

add_action( 'init','addsomerule' );
```

It ensures that the rule is added only during admin requests.

However, the `if` statement that calls a function comes with a (little) cost in term of performance, and considering that the `add_rewrite_rule` is not very expensive (it only writes a value to a global array, and does not hit db), then probably it does not worth to add that condition.

Moreover, you don't always have control on all the code your site uses. If *some* plugin calls `flush_rewrite_rules()` on frontend requests, then your rule is lost because added only on backend.

For all these reasons, add rewrite rules on `init` without any other check is probably the right thing to do: it avoids any issue and the little costs it adds on frontend requests is pretty much irrelevant and lost in the WordPress boot time.

Comment: I am actually wrong  but it is not exactly the reason you gave. I was just hoping that someone will have an answer to the other part of the question (better hook....). The reason that without any other alternative you have to hook on init is because web servers execute several requests at "parallel" which means that the next request after a flush might actually be a front end request and it will be the one that generates the rewrite_rule option.

Comment: @MarkKaplun As I said, the 2 only hooks you can use are `init` and `wp_loaded`, and there's no real reason to prefer one over the other in this context. Any other later hook simply does not work, and use an earlier hook with no reason, is just bad. So, actually, `init` *is* the better hook for the scope.

Comment: Regarding the race condition you talk about, the possibility it happen is closer to 0. `flush_rewrite_rules` delete the option and the line right after, it updates the option. The possibility that something happen in between of two consecutive PHP lines is pretty much 0 even with thousands of contemporary users. And yes, allowing frontend to update the db prevent that such a race condition, but surely is not the most relevant reason to use init over other hooks.

Comment: Yes you are right the window is very small but it does bound to happen at some point to someone. Anyway I am not sure that the whole thing can not be done better but at least there is semi logical explanation.

Comment: Regarding the window of opportunity, keep in mind that the executing thread is likely to give up the CPU for a blocking IO and it will also do so if it exhausts it's quantum.

Comment: @MarkKaplun: there is a reason to use wp_loaded : at that time, you will be able to get a post type object using get_post_type_object() [which I was needing]], and that it is not possible at the time of 'init'.

Comment: @gordie `wp_loaded` should be used when you can assume that initialization is finished, and it might be questionable if it was finished before all the rewrite rule were properly added.

Comment: @MarkKaplun good point, but then how can you build rewrite rules that depend on the post type object ? - like getting the `$post_type_obj->rewrite['slug']` value ?

Comment: @gordie, well I did use "should" and not "must" because some situations are just not easy to fit into theory. I would say that if you know when the CPT is added (assuming it is added early on `init`) you can just use higher priority, or better use one of the hooks being triggered when the CPT is added or the rewrite rules being generated.